# What is Attach Path effect's function in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I try Path effect in Inkscape, and I encounter one effect that makes me confused how to do it which is Attach Path effect. I check Inkscape wikipedia and here's the info

"Attach Path LPE

Connect a path to another path (optionally at each end), by attaching it to a specified location on the other path (specified as in ., or by dragging a handle).

The connecting curve segment can be shaped with handles, or by entering a number.

This LPE makes it possible for the first time to have 'crossings' between paths that move with the path when it is modified, which isn't possible within the SVG specification."

Wikipedia Source : https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Release_notes/0.92#Attach_Path

And here is the example of how this path being used [image]

Meanwhile, I don't know how to connect the path using this effect, and I'm stuck. Can somebody explain this effect? It's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get it to work.

1. Draw a line, which must be an open path
2. Draw a second object, which can be a shape or another open path
3. Select the second object, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard.
4. Select the first line you made, and apply the Attach Path LPE
5. In the Path Effects dialog hit this button, highlighted red below, to add the copied object (in the clipboard)

[image]

6. Select the line with the Edit Paths by nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, and you can adjust the control points that determine where the joining segment is attached, or the angle/curve it makes with the object.
7. If you select the connected object you can move it and the connection moves with it.

A quick example:

[image]

**Note:** in the Path Effects dialog, you can connect different objects to the start of the path, or the end of the path. You will need to scroll down the panel to see where to add objects to the end of the path.

Several of the LPE effects work in a similar way, where you copy an object and use the copy in the clipboard to interact with the object to which the effect has been applied.

Comment: Hi.... It is working, I thought at first I must duplicate the object, for I mistakenly take "Copy" for "Duplicate" lol.

Comment: @EarvinWilliams Yeah, just copy to the clipboard!! I've edited the steps to make it clearer now.